# How do i make current nav link which is also home page active when it's the current page?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, web, nav

So i had the working solution untill i decided to change my home page(because it was just an empty page) to one of my nav links. Now when i click on the navlink it redirects me to the home page which has no url, thus the link can't be found. This is the code that i used before:

```
    var activePage = window.location.pathname;
        
        const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav a").
            forEach(link => {        
                    if (link.href.includes(activePage)) {
                        link.classList.add("current");
        }   });
```

This is what i tried

```
var activePage = window.location.pathname;
if (activePage == "/") {
    activePage="/ProjectsList"
}
var d = document.getElementById("navLink3");
/*d.className += "current";*/
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav a").
    forEach(link => {
     
            if (activePage == "/AdminPage" || activePage == "/Account/UserProfile") {
            if (link.href.includes(activePage)) {
                link.classList.add("current");
                }
            }
            else {
                d.className += "current";
            console.log("wok")}
        
        
        
    });
```

it technically reaches the else statement but the class doesn't get applied.
I want to mention that i use asp.net and i changed the index page by writing in the .cshtml of the nav page `@page "/"`
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

can you do this:

```
d.className = "current";
Instead of:-
d.className += "current";
```